# JavaScript calling function with different signatures

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am facing a problem while calling `processRequest` function from javascript. I need two `ProcessRequest` function with different signature. Like:

```
processRequest();
processRequest(strFieldName);
```

But the prob is when I write the second function and call the first function like:

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest ;
```

It gives a error `'req' undefined`. But after commenting out the 2nd function the 1st function works well. Even if I put `( )` while calling the 1st function it shows `type mismatch` error. But in anyway the 2nd function works.

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of processRequest();

inside processRequest(strFieldName) have code such as:

```
if(strFieldName){
   ...code that needs parameter
}
else {
   ..code that doesn't need parameter
}
```